# What PCI Bus ID is 0x1?

Tags: linux, pci-express, pci, hardware-detection, pci-x

I need to find what is connected at Bus id 0x1. On Linux doing `lspci` I got the bus ids in a different format such as 00:01.0. I guess these are same, just x is used instead of ':' in the first instance. Meaning Bus Id 0x1=00:01.0. Am I right? If not then, what will 0x1 be in the format I got using `lspci`?

Answer (score 0):

In `lspci` output, `00:01.0` means "bus 0, device 1, function 0".

I can't say what is Bus id 0x1, but if there is only one bus, then
you might effectively have found the right device.

For more information, see
[Interpreting the output of lspci](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=649b7a71b35fc7ad41e03b6d0e825f07).